# Is document the object available to the email action in Alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to access the document object's properties using the email action that is part of the OOTB options in the rules creation dialog drop down options like in this picture:

[image: alfresco share rule options]

But that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

This dialog uses the `mail` action defined by `org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MailActionExecuter`.

If you need custom logic, I would rather introduce a new action than change the default because people may expect default behavior at "Send email". Depending on your needs, the quickest solution may be to just create a custom server side script in the data dictionary which just calls the default action appropriately. There is an example at https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Actions_API. You would pick "Execute Script" in this case. Alternatively, you could introduce a  custom action deriving from the default implementation.

If all you need is accessing the properties in the mail template, it may be enough to introduce a custom freemarker template. In this case, just set the value of the `template` action paramter to a noderef you want to use. In this template,  you have the document properties available as "${document.properties}.

Comment: I forgot to reply to this. I provided a custom template but still receive an error when trying to send the mail ( java.io.IOException: No content). Though in the script it is possible to output the document properties through the logger. I think this might be a bug in the 4.2.f.